# localStorage Add to Cart

Tags: jquery, local-storage, shopping-cart

I'm creating a simple **add to cart** feature using jQuery and `localStorage`. Everything works fine, but I cannot add a `selected` class to the Add to Cart button. Please help me to add and remove (toggle) the `selected` class.

I need the logic to set the class on the buttons based on whether or not the product is held in the JSON I am holding in localStorage.

```js
var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];
var list = $("#fav-list");
var parent = list.parent();

function addFavList() {
  list.detach().empty().each(function(i) {
    for (var x = 0; x < favorites.length; x++) {
      $(this).append('<li>' + favorites[x] + '</li>');
      if (x == favorites.length - 1) {
        $(this).appendTo(parent);
      }

    }
  });
}

addFavList();

$(document).delegate('.cart', 'click', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).parent().html(),
    index = favorites.indexOf(id);

  if (!id) 
    return;

  if (index == -1) {
    favorites.push(id);
  } else {
    favorites.splice(index, 1);
    $(this).parent().removeClass('fav');
  }

  localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
  addFavList();
});


$(document).delegate('#delete', 'click', function() {
  localStorage.clear();
  location.reload();
});
```

Please check this [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8adbjstz/2/) where I have tried my best

Comment: @roryMcCrossan, I have tried that toggle class and it is working on while clicking but that selected class is not  saving in localstorage.

Comment: Yes your are right

Comment: I have updated the question for you to make it clearer.

Comment: @ilmk added an answer that I think might help.

Comment: onclick of every `.cart`, remove from all `.cart` class `selected`, add class `selected` to the one that from onlclick event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have little workout in your fiddle and i think may be its now as you want.

Its now toggling class `selected` on deleting and adding to cart.

I have edited fiddle and here is code.

```
var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];


var list = $("#fav-list");
var parent = list.parent();

function addFavList(){
      $(document).find('.cart').removeClass('selected');
      list.detach().empty().each(function(i){

      for (var x = 0; x < favorites.length; x++){
           $(this).append('<li>' + favorites[x] + '</li>');

           $('.list li').each(function(){
               if($(this).html() == favorites[x]){
                   $(this).find('.cart').addClass('selected')
               }
            });
            if (x == favorites.length - 1){
            $(this).appendTo(parent);


           }
       }
    });

}
addFavList();

$(document).delegate('.cart', 'click', function(e){
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    var id = $(this).parent().html();

    var index = favorites.indexOf(id);


    if (!id) return;
        if (index == -1) {
        favorites.push(id);
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    } 
    else {
       favorites.splice(index, 1);
       $(this).parent().removeClass('fav');
       $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }

    localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
    addFavList();
});


$(document).delegate('#delete', 'click', function(){
   localStorage.clear();
   location.reload();   
   $(document).find('.cart').removeClass('selected');
});
```

I'm not sure its totally satisfactory to you but hope it will be useful.

Here is fiddle link also. please try will clearing localstorage.
https://jsfiddle.net/8adbjstz/75/

Comment: Perfect.. It's really nice. Thank You !!

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest to store only **item names** into `localStorage` array. like `["iPhone","Samsung","Macbook Pro"]` not with the html links elements. it helps in comparison while store or retrive the values.

check updated code in `jsfiddle` https://jsfiddle.net/shivkumar/o9xabdtr/

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var favorites = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('favorites')) || [];

  var list = $("#fav-list");
  var parent = list.parent();

  function addFavList(){
    list.detach().empty().each(function(i){
        for (var x = 0; x < favorites.length; x++){
        $(this).append('<li><a href="#">'+ favorites[x] + '</a><button class="cart selected">Remove cart</button></li>');
        $(this).appendTo(parent);
            $('.list').find("li:contains("+ favorites[x] +")").find('.cart').addClass('selected');
            $('.list').find("li:contains("+ favorites[x] +")").find('.cart').html('Remove cart');
        }
    });

  }

  addFavList();

  $(document).delegate('.cart', 'click', function(e){

    var item = $(this.parentElement.firstElementChild).text();
    index = favorites.indexOf(item);

    if (!item) return;
    if (index == -1) {
        favorites.push(item);
    }
    else {
      $('.list').find("li:contains("+ favorites[index] +")").find('.cart').removeClass('selected');
      $('.list').find("li:contains("+ favorites[index] +")").find('.cart').html('Add to cart');
      favorites.splice(index, 1);
    }

    localStorage.setItem('favorites', JSON.stringify(favorites));
    addFavList();
  });


  $(document).delegate('#delete', 'click', function(){
     localStorage.clear();
     location.reload();
  });

});
```

**CSS**

```
ul, ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  min-width: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

.selected {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

#res, #fav-list {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

.cart {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}

.fav {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.selected {
  background: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<html>

<body>

  <ul class="list">
    <li><a href="#">iPhone</a><button class="cart">Add to cart</button></li>
    <li><a href="#">Samsung</a><button class="cart">Add to cart</button></li>
    <li><a href="#">Macbook Pro</a><button class="cart">Add to cart</button></li>
    <li><a href="#">Dell Laptop</a><button class="cart">Add to cart</button></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <br/>
  <div id="res">

  Your Cart

    <ul id="fav-list">

    </ul>
    <br/>

  </div>

  <button id="delete">Delete</button>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In some cases, it's best to move steps that are repeated often to function. Consider the following jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  function getFavData() {
    var data = localStorage.getItem('favorites');
    var fav = JSON.parse(data) || [];
    console.log("Getting Data", fav);
    return fav
  }

  function saveFavData(data) {
    if (typeof data === 'object') {
      data = JSON.stringify(data);
    } else {
      data = JSON.stringify([data]);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('favorites', data);
    console.log("Saving Data", data);
    return true;
  }

  function showFavData(target) {
    var list = getFavData();
    target.empty();
    console.log("Showing Data", target, list);
    $.each(list, function(k, v) {
      $("<li>").html(v).appendTo(target);
    });
  }

  function clearFavData(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var res = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete all the items in your Cart?");
    if (res) {
      localStorage.setItem('favorites', '');
      localStorage.clear();
      location.reload();
      console.log("Data Cleared");
    }
  }

  $(".cart").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var list = getFavData();
    var item = $(this).prev("a").text();
    var index = list.indexOf(item);

    if (!item) return;
    if (index == -1) {
      list.push(item);
    } else {
      list.splice(index, 1);
      $(this).parent().removeClass('fav');
    }
    saveFavData(list);
    showFavData($("#fav-list"));
  });

  $('#delete').click(clearFavData);
});
```

You can see a working example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3wmvou45/34/

Even if they are small, splitting up the work allows you to perform those actions at any point in your script. It can make your script look cleaner and easier to understand later if you ever have to go back and rebuild it. Proper comments or good naming conventions can help you identify the specific jobs that each function will carry out.

Your code can also benefit from some extra checks. Like when deleting, making sure the User really wants to delete all the data. Or when saving data, making sure it's an array of data that is being saved.

Unless your HTML Elements are being dynamically created, you should not need to use `.delegate()`. If HTML is being generated programmatically, I would advise using `.on()` instead.

> As of jQuery 3.0, `.delegate()` has been deprecated. It was superseded by the `.on()` method since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.

A number of your selectors and code were also not correct. For example:

```
var id = $(this).parent().html();
```

In this code snippet, `$(this)`, refers to the button that was clicked. `.parent()` selects the parent element of the button, that being the `<li>` element. Finally, `.html()` returns the `innerHTML` of the `<li>`. So in the end, `id` would contain:

```
<a href="#">iPhone</a><button class="cart">Add to cart</button>
```

This would then fail when trying to identify if this item exists in the array. Since you simple wanted `"iPhone"` string, you would want to select the `.text()` of the `<a>` element. Either way could work for you:

- `var id = $(this).parent().find("a").text();`
- `var id = $(this).prev("a").text();`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).delegate('.cart', 'click', function(e){
           ///*** Try using $target to add selected class to button///
             $target = $(e.target);   
            $target.addClass('selected');
    var id = $(this).parent().html(),
    index = favorites.indexOf(id);

    if (!id) return;
        if (index == -1) {
        favorites.push(id);
    } 
    else {
      ///*** Try using $target to remove selected class from button///
        $target.removeClass('selected');
        favorites.splice(index, 1);
        $(this).parent().removeClass('fav');
    }
```

Comment: If I refresh, the selected class removed from main list.

Comment: @ilmk hi, i added jsfiddle link to my answer. https://jsfiddle.net/ercanpeker/zngc5v1b/